# How to convert STRUCT to STRING in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

How to convert STRUCT into a STRING representation in BigQuery

```
select struct("John" as name, 23 as age,"IT" as department) as mystruct
```

A JSON representation would be ok. Something like `{"name":"John","age":23,"department":"IT"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it - [TO_JSON_STRING](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#to_json_string)

```
with mydata as (
  select struct("John" as name, 23 as age,"IT" as department) as mystruct
) 
select TO_JSON_STRING(mystruct) from mydata

/*-----------+--------------------------------*
 | {"name":"John","age":23,"department":"IT"} |
 *--------------------------------------------*/
```